# Find parent of unwrapped element and use it in .wrap() using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically added `div` elements with structure as follows.

```
<div class="blogPost">
  <a href="link/to/full_artical">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
  </a>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to remove `a` wrappers from `h1` elements and add them to parent `div` elements. The result should be like:

```
<a href="link/to/full_artical">
  <div class="blogPost">
     <h1>Some Heading</h1>
     <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
     </p>
  </div>
</a>
```

I wish there is a way in `jquery` maybe a combination of `unwrap()`  and `wrap()` functions.

- I do not have access to the source of this dynamically added content.
- divs are being added dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

tried

`$('.blogPost').wrap('<a href="'+$(this).children('a').attr('href')+'"></a>')`

Not Working.

Comment: Have you tried to unwrap() and then wrappAll() just as you said? What was the outcome? Seems that you know what to do but you are looking forward a copy-paste solution here.

Comment: Please put your js here

Comment: Because you used `$(this)` while it doen't defined.

Comment: @PrakharSingh If you have multiple `.blogPost` See [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ymeLmve8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copying `a` element and store it in variable. Use [`.unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to remove `a` parent of `h1` and use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrapping copied element around `.blogPost`.

```js
var clone = $("a").clone().children().remove().end();
$("h1").unwrap().parent().wrap(clone);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blogPost">
  <a href="link/to/full_artical">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
  </a>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```js
var href = $('.blogPost').children('a').attr('href');
$('.blogPost').wrap('<a href="'+href+'"></a>');
$('h1').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blogPost">
  <a href="link/to/full_artical">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
  </a>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Its bad idea to create new anchor tag. If element has another attribute (class, id, title, ...) the code doesn't work properly.

Comment: Thanks, I just have to iterate through all the `.blogPost`s. with this code. Can you please tell me why is `$('.blogPost').wrap('<a href="'+$(this).children('a').attr('href')+'"></a>')` not working.

Comment: You mean you have more than one `blogPost` classes in your html? @PrakharSingh

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = $('a'),
    heading = link.find('h1'),
    blogPost = $('.blogPost');

blogPost.prepend(heading);
blogPost.wrap(link);
link.remove();
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/QEqdLw)

Comment: I would also get the queried blogPost anchor child element attr('href') and then add it back respectively, as it seems to be a main functionality here.